# Placing tools panel on the left side of ag grid

Tags: grid

By default, ag grid has a tool panel on right side of the grid. How do I place it on left side? Also, can I provide aggregation data beside each column listed in tool panel? Please provide hint for the same.

Answer (score 1):

According to [ag-Grid's sidebar documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/#sidebardef-configuration) it should be possible to move the tool panel to the left by specifying `position: 'left'` in the sidebar configuration.

e.g.

```
sideBar = {
    toolPanels: [
        {
            id: 'columns',
            labelDefault: 'Columns',
            labelKey: 'columns',
            iconKey: 'columns',
            toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
        }
    ],
    position: 'left'
}
```